# How can I display a list in tabs or pagination in django?

Tags: html, css, django

I am currently working on a django project where in from views.py, I am calling a function to render my HTML page and I am passing an argument which is list of lists. I want to display these lists in tabs or pagination where only first list is active and others are in pagination, how can I do that? And the list of lists I am passing may have different number of items in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the example how to achieve tabs. Of course you have to write specific css to make it look like a tab.

```
# Views.py    
    lists = [[1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8], [9]]

    #Template 
        {# loop through your list of lists #}
        {% for list in lists %}
            {# apply class active for first tab #}
            <div class="tab {% if forloop.counter0 == 0 %}active{% endif %}">
                 <ul>
                   {# loop through inner list #}
                   {% for element in list %}
                       <li>{{ element }}</li>
                   {% endfor %}
                 </ul>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
```